# How do you join tables sharing the same column?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I made an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cf4e/3) and what I would like to do is join these two queries by using the `departmentid`.

What I would like to show is the `departmentname` and `not_approved_manager`.

Would it be best to use a union or join in this case?

**Tables**

```
create table cserepux
(
   status int, 
   comment varchar(25),
   departmentid int,
   approveddate datetime 
);

insert into cserepux (status, comment, departmentid, approveddate)
values (1, 'testing1', 1, NULL), (1, 'testing2', 1, NULL),
       (1, 'testing2', 2, NULL), (0, 'testing2', 1, NULL),
       (0, 'tesitng2', 1, NULL), (0, 'testing2', 1, NULL),
       (0, 'tesitng2', 1, NULL), (0, 'testing3', 2, NULL),
       (0, 'testing3', 3, NULL);

create table cseDept 
(
    departmentid int, 
    department_name varchar(25)
);

insert into cseDept (departmentid,department_name)
values (1, 'department one'), (2, 'department two'),
       (3, 'department three'), (4, 'department four');
```

**Query**

```
select 
    departmentid, 
    COUNT(*) AS 'not_approved_manager'
from 
    cserepux
where 
    approveddate is null
group by 
    departmentid

SELECT * FROM cseDept
```

Comment: I added the contents of your fiddle to the question so that the necessary information is here for future readers.  If you feel that I have put something in incorrectly, please feel free to fix it or revert the edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a join.  A union will not get you what you want.

```
select d.department_name, COUNT(*) AS 'not_approved_manager'
from cserepux c
inner join cseDept d on c.departmentid = d.departmentid
where approveddate is null
group by d.department_name
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you need just a join and a correct group by

```
  select dep.department_name, COUNT(*) AS 'not_approved_manager'
  from cseDept dep
  join cserepux cs on cs.departmentid = dep.departmentid
  where approveddate is null
  group by dep.department_name
```

**Fiddle:** http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5cf4e/30

Since *joins* and *group by* are really basic things in SQL I can suggest you do take a look on some tutorials to get a bit more proficiency whit it. You can try [SQL Server Central](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/) stairway articles series